# Apache Drill does not close file handles?

Tags: apache-drill

My setup:

- Drill running in embedded mode
- SMB (azure files) storage mounted to /data
- Some parquet files inside the /data folder

I'm running some simple queries against the parquets.

If the query ends with any error, the target parquet files remain locked and I cannot write/delete them until I restart the Drill.

This does not happen when the query is successful.

Any ideas?